# Feching user's current location tips

Tags: python, ruby, django, dictionary, location

I was asked to create a web app that uses user current location to determine a distance to a given place.
I have never faced this kind of problem so i'm looking for some guideline, efficient technologies/libraries that allow to implement such mechanism also some pro tips from someone with experiance would be really appreciated.
I often develop my apps with Ruby on Rails/Django but i can adapt to other technologies if beneficial. I did research and found some geo libs but i'm really looking for some guidance from someone with experiance casue i want to do it right.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you really have two options.

The first, and most likely to be accurate, is to ask the user through their browser via javascript, what their location is. HTML5 allows you to do this through geolocation:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation/Using_geolocation

The basics are as follows:

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
  do_something(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
});
```

Obviously, this requires the user to agree to sharing their location with you. Which brings us to option 2 ... approximate location by IP.

From the users IP you can use one of a number of services to translate an IP address to a physical location. The results can be somewhat varied though, and if the user is using any kind of VPN, proxy, etc, then you can be completely incorrect with your guess of where they actually are.

Here's a free API you could start off with - https://freegeoip.net/